# How to use jpa:repositories with proxy-target-class="true"

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-data

I use

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxwell.amkey.domain"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

It works like a charm. However, to add aspects to the project, I need CGLIB. Changing the above lines to

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxwell.amkey.domain"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

leads to a failure in starting the context: `Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy45` for each of my defined repositories. Is it impossible to use together, or can it be done?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if you need cglib style proxy, then you'll have to remove the @Transactional annotation from your repository interface, and move it to the service/s class/es that call it.

Comment: @Luciano, I have not yet come around to testing this, but anyway: Please write that as an answer, so I can accept it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need cglib style proxy, then you'll have to remove the @Transactional annotation from your repository interface, and move it to the service/s class/es that call it.

CGLIB style augmenting works directly on the classes it augments. The interfaces don't matter.

Comment: I’d love to really understand why that is, but you are right. The docs did not seem to mention that.

Comment: @MPi JDK proxy works with interfaces. If your class A implements B, then it builds a Proxy B' that also implements B, and wraps A. So you still see B, and when it calls function f(), the aspect takes place before (or after) the function A.f(). For the proxy to know what to wrap, the annonations must annotate the interface methods, because it doesn't really care about A, as long as it implements B. CGLIB on the other hand, enhances the class A. It doesn't care what interfaces it implements. So for it to know what to enhance, the annotation must reside in the class A.

Answer (score 0):

final methods cannot be advised, as they cannot be overriden. Maybe one of your parent class have final method or your class is final.

Comment: That is true. However, the failure message is for my Spring Data repositories, which are interfaces (so nothing is final).

Answer (score 0):

Other option is get rid of

```
proxy-target-class="true"
```

by introducing proper interfaces in all AOP places (suppose at service layer)